# I don't under stand why compare Numbers function switch parameters?

Tags: javascript

I have this function here that compares number to sort an array during the sort it should take a and b parameters problems in console log the parameter go b to a instead as they are stated why is this switching happening ? in other words how the compareNumbers function decide on what is a and what is b.
also is this a native pre defined function by the way ? because taking a and b doesn't make any sense to me.

```js
let array1 = ['6', '10', '9']
let array2 = ['90', '9', '1']

function mergeSortedArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    let merge = arr1.concat(arr2)
    // merge = ['6', '10', '9','90', '9', '1']
    merge.sort(compareNumbers)
    
    function compareNumbers(a, b) {
        console.log(a, b);
        // a = 10 b = 6 
        // a = 9 b = 10
        return a - b;
    }
    return merge
}
console.log(mergeSortedArrays(array1, array2));
```

Comment: "Switching"? We don't control the parameters provided to the sort function callback; an implementation is allowed to call the callback with parameters in whatever order makes sense to it.

Comment: @MisterJojo The question is about the parameters passed to the `sort` callback, though, not the sort order. (Noting that at least for my JS impl the param type doesn't matter if the arrays provided above are strings or ints--which *can* matter since the data type may influence the JS engine's choice of algorithms)

Comment: so is it a pre defined function ? build in to the JavaScript by default.

Comment: @Connective-tissue What is? `Array.prototype.sort`? Yes; where else would it be?

Comment: Array.prototype.sort sure is a native but when compareNumbers(a, b) is the argument then ?? which function decided on the a,b order ?

Comment: The function that calls it; "sort". Like any other function call.